# How does Firefox auto update work?

Tags: windows, firefox, browser, updates

I am little confused as to how does Firefox auto update works?

So, lately, Firefox had a bug in 38.x version - so they recommended to update to the latest version.

I had auto update turned on, so I thought it would auto update automatically. So, I click on Help > About Firefox, it was still 38.x

However, after I clicked on the About Firefox, it started downloading the updates, and prompted to restart the Firefox to install them.

I replicated it on a different machine (with auto updates turned on) and same result.

So, I am wondering if I have to trigger the download manually, how does really auto update works. Or am I missing something.

Note: New version was released about 2 days ago, so it wasn't right away I checked the download.

Comment: Hmm Windows Firefox is currently on 40.0.2. Mine has been auto updating just fine 38 > 39 > 40. Are you running an ESR release? "Extended Support Release (ESR) based on an official release of Firefox for desktop for use by organizations including schools, universities, businesses and others who need extended support for mass deployments. "

Comment: Is there way to check if I am running ESR? I mean the updates are set to 'release' not 'esr' in the channel-pref.

Comment: Is there a way to manually trigger the Help > About Firefox menu via script or something?

Comment: A check for updates is usually made when you start firefox. See [Advanced panel - Accessibility, browsing, network, updates, and other advanced settings in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/advanced-panel-settings-in-firefox?redirectlocale=en-US&as=u&redirectslug=Options+window+-+Advanced+panel&utm_source=inproduct#w_update-tab) for how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox always checks for update at startup(when Firefox is launched).If update is found,then Firefox starts downloading in the background without disturbing browsing ie when Firefox is not loading any tabs.It will take sometime to finish downloading as it only uses  bandwidth ,when Firefox is idle(not loading tabs) and download stops, when you exit Firefox.

In your case,Firefox was downloading updates and when you checked  in "about Firefox",Firefox just resumed the update from where it stopped.

Note:Firefox uses Mozilla maintenance service to do this.And people with high speed internet will not even know that update has taken place.But people with low speed internet can feel it.